# Applying number format on dropdown appended array

Tags: javascript

Applying number format on dropdown appended array

```
arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data); <br>
                  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){<br>
                     $("#input_car_model").append(new Option(arr[i]['model']+" ("+arr[i]['cnt']+" 대)", arr[i]['model']));
                  }
```

Hello, I have a question about number_format 
This part `"arr[i]['cnt']"` is number, and i want it to be shown like 100,000. 
How can I apply number_format in this case? 
Thank you!

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14428340/6582942

Comment: I already read that but.. anything worked inside [ ]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the same scenario and it worked for me. Check below code

```
var t = {1: [100000]};
t.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'); // gives "100,000.00"
```